# How can I use a decorated name with _Generic?

Tags: c, generics, macros

I'm writing a library which lets the user decorate the function names like this:

```c
#ifndef DECORATE // Define this before including if you want to change the names.
#define DECORATE(name) lib_##name
#endif
```

I now what to use `_Generic` to create a generic function `foo` like this:

```c
#define DECORATE(foo)(x)            \
    _Generic((x),                   \
             int:   DECORATE(fooi), \
             float: DECORATE(foof)  \
    )(x)
```

This of course gives me an error, because I can't define the `DECORATE` macro twice. Is there a way to decorate the name of the generic function or is this impossible?

Comment: This is overall a bad idea. It makes far more sense to use _Generic to decide which function to call rather than which to create. Having macros that declare functions are almost always the wrong solution to the wrong problem to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your macros two different names so one can use the other.  Also, in the case of the one using `_Generic`, both parameters need to be in one set of parenthesis separated by spaces.

```
#ifndef DECORATEX 
#define DECORATEX(name) lib_##name
#endif

#define DECORATE(foo,x)            \
    _Generic((x),                   \
             int:   DECORATEX(foo##i), \
             float: DECORATEX(foo##f)  \
    )(x)


void lib_abci(int x)
{
    printf("in abci, x=%d\n", x);
}

void lib_abcf(float x)
{
    printf("in abcf, x=%f\n", x);
}

int main()
{
    int a=3;
    float b=4.5;
    DECORATE(abc,a);
    DECORATE(abc,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
in abci, x=3
in abcf, x=4.500000
```

Comment: This does mean that the user has to call `DECORATE` each time they want to use the function, which is pretty inconvenient. Is there no way to let the user simply call `lib_foo()`?

Comment: @durkadomida You could use a function pointer, but that would only be possible if the arguments of each function are the same type, which they are not.  It seems like what you're asking for is for macro names to be created on the fly which is also not possible.